# Spring Boot Caching / MySQL with 2 parallel applications and one database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, caching

Our application is deployed twice on different machines with a load balancer in front. Both share the same database (MySQL cluster).
In order to speed up lot's of things in the ui I wanted to use the spring boot caching things on certain tables / database queries...

But... how can this be done if application 1 changes something within the database which is in the cache of application 2? Is there some nice approach to reset the cache on application 2? Or do I have to solve this "by hand" (counting entries, comparing 'lastUpdated' columns...) to reset the cache in application 2?

Or should I use a special cache table where application 1 tells application 2 that some data has changed?

Not quite sure what a common solution for this particular problem can be...

Thanks in advance!